# Fatal error undefined function curl() when using json_decode and cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

Hello all i want to use cURL to send $_POST to another server, but i got a Fatal Error Call to undefined function curl() what im missing ? 
PS: i have already a php file who is running cURL very well in the same server so im sure that the server is configured to use cURL .

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    set_time_limit(0);
   $status = json_decode(curl($_POST), true); // Here is the error line 
}

function curl($arra) {
{
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $arra['ip'] = $ip;
    $ckfile = tempnam("./tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init("site.com/file.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arra);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $c = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $c;
}
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$details     = simplexml_load_file("www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=" . $ip . "");
$codecountry = $details->geoplugin_countryCode;
$countryname = $details->geoplugin_countryName;
$codecountry2 = strtolower($codecountry);
```

This is the line with error

```
$status = json_decode(curl($_POST), true);
```

Comment: I see not call to a `Test()` function in your code. Please check this code is actually relevant to your question

Comment: im sorry i want to mean call to a curl()

Answer (score 0):

```
function curl($arra) {
{
```

There is an extra curly bracket you must delete, also there is no `Test()` method.

Comment: `$status = json_decode(curl($_POST), true); // Here is the error line`